# Selenium ChromeDriver смена proxy

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как менять `proxy` в `Selenium ChromeDriver` ?

Т.е. посетить сайт на одном `IP` и при сёрфинге на нём изменять `IP` не перезапуская сам `ChromeDriver`

Как задать начальный прокси я знаю

```
options.AddArguments($"--proxy-server={proxy}");
```

А вот как менять на лету ?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, никак. Да и не для парсинга селениум придумали, а для автотестов сайтов при разработке. Чем вам обычный `HttpClient` не угодил? Работает быстрее, а в сетевом смысле может то же самое, что и любой браузер.

Comment: @aepot на `HttpClient` не удаётся мне проходить `ReCaptcha v3`, в отличии от использования браузера.

Comment: @aepot может есть конечно что то более универсальное чем `Selenium` под `C#`, но я на такое ещё не нарвался(

Comment: Есть CefSharp, есть WebView2 на худой конец. Но там проблема с проксями будет скорее всего схожая, хоть и не придется запускать полноценный браузер. Компромисс, так сказать.